# Message with Anchor Tag is not properly showing in the Angular Material Snackbar

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-material

I am creating an application with .net core and Angular. I am sending a **notification message** from my asp.net background worker. In the notification there is a link. Now I am using the **Angular Material Snackbar** to show this notification message with the link. But instead of showing the link it's showing the plain message with anchor tag.

Here is the .net core code:

```
string msg = @"Click <a href=""http://localhost:4200/#/download/testFile.zip"" target=""_blank"">Here</a> to download the zip file";
UserIdentifier user1 = new UserIdentifier(1, 2);                    
_notificationPublisher.PublishAsync("mymessage",new MessageNotificationData(msg),severity: NotificationSeverity.Info,userIds: new[] { user1 })
```

I have created a component in angular to show within the snackbar. Here is the code:

```
<span class="example">
    {{data}}
</span>

<button (click)="snackBarRef.dismiss()">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Here is the ts file:

```
export class CustomSnackbarComponent {
    constructor(
        public snackBarRef: MatSnackBarRef<CustomSnackbarComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any
    ) { }
}
```

Here is the function where I called that custom snackbar

```
configSuccess: MatSnackBarConfig = {
    panelClass: 'style-success',
    horizontalPosition: 'center',
    verticalPosition: 'top'
};

openSnackBar(notifyMessage) {
    this._snackBar.openFromComponent(CustomSnackbarComponent, {
        data: notifyMessage,
        ...this.configSuccess
    });
}
```

And here is the output I get:

[image]

The snackbar is shwoing the full html code. Can anyone help me resolve the problem. Instead of shwoing the html code I need to show the **Here** text. And when user will click on the **"Here"** text link will open an another window.